# jquery mobile checkbox form data

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I am struggling to figure out how to pass check box info in jquery mobile for a form. In the form I have the following set of check boxs for users to select what clubs they want:

```html
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Select Set?</legend>
    <option value=""></option>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t123_irons" id="t123_irons" class="custom" value="3">
    <label for="t123_irons">3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t124_irons" id="t124_irons" class="custom" value="4">
    <label for="t124_irons">4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t125_irons" id="t125_irons" class="custom" value="5">
    <label for="t125_irons">5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t126_irons" id="t126_irons" class="custom" value="6">
    <label for="t126_irons">6</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t127_irons" id="t127_irons" class="custom" value="7">
    <label for="t127_irons">7</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t128_irons" id="t128_irons" class="custom" value="8">
    <label for="t128_irons">8</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t129_irons" id="t129_irons" class="custom" value="9">
    <label for="t129_irons">9</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="t12pw_irons" id="t12pw_irons" class="custom" value="PW">
    <label for="t12pw_irons">PW</label>
  </fieldset>
</li>
```

I am not sure what to put on my review form to get the checkboxs that are selected since in jQuery mobile the check box group all have different IDs and Names for checkbox groups.This is how I imagine I would get the group if they had one unified name/id:

```php
echo (!empty($_REQUEST['t12_irons'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>In Set:</span>{$_REQUEST['t12_irons']}</div>" : "";
```

Comment: You mean to find out whether checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: trying to pull the values so on the review part of the form it will list the clubs selected (i.e. 3,6,pw)

Comment: `$('#id').prop('checked')` this will return either true or false.

Comment: okay so I would have to do that for each check box? There is not a way to just list all the boxs selected in a fieldset?

Comment: If you want to know the checked ones `$('[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')`.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xvgyZ/

Comment: @Omar Thanks that makes sense. What I am doing is passing all the form data to a Review.php that echos all the field info and if it looks correct the user can submit which sends the data to a Submit.php file that emails the info. How can I echo the check box data? There are several check boxs also. Here is the full file [link](http://jsfiddle.net/packytagliaferro/gFQqV/)